# Model-selection for linear mixed models over alternative sets of parameters (nlme function in R)

Tags: mixed-model, model-selection, goodness-of-fit, aic, r-squared

My models look like:

```
lme1 = lme(y~X+Y+V, random=~1|Subject, data=mydata, method ="ML")
lme2 = lme(y~X+Y+V2+V3, random=~1|Subject, data=mydata, method ="ML")
lme3 = lme(y~X+Y+V4, random=~1|Subject, data=mydata, method ="ML")
```

where X and Y are factors, but V, V2, V3,and V4 are continuous variables (modeled as covariates). I am using `Method ="ML"` in the hope that I could compare the likelihood values across the models.

My research question has to do with whether V4 (in lme3) was a better predictor than V2 and V3 together, V2+V3 was better than V, etc. What goodness of fits measure is valid here?  Can I use AIC values to compare models of different sets of parameters?

I've also found some references on computing $R^2$ for mixed models.  In particular, I am interested in the likelihood ratio test $R^2$ ([Magee, 1990](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00031305.1990.10475731)) which computes a $R^2$ by comparing each of these models to the null model. Using this method, I'd be comparing all three of my models to the same null model with just `y~1`.  Is it then a valid approach to compare the $R^2$s generated?

I am not a statistician but I would like to use a valid (at least justifiable) measure for my analysis. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since the models are fit by maximum likelihood, AIC would be defensible here.

Comment: @Macro: thanks for your comment. Could you elaborate on how AIC would be defensible here, when it comes down to comparing models Lme2 and LME3, even though they are non-nested and the number of variables are different?  There seemed to be some disagreements over whether AICs can be used in non-nested models. Should I be concerned about that?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The AIC is an estimate of the (relative) Kullback-Leibler information. There is no reason to believe that it is applicable only for nested models (I actually don't know why people think that).

Comment: @Néstor Very true. You can use likelihood-ratio tests for nested models. AIC and the like are **especially useful for non-nested models** (i.e., situations where you cannot use likelihood-ratio tests).

Comment: I agree with everyone about AIC, but I just wanted to point out that in the code you have above, `y` is being modelled as continuous, even though you say it's a factor. You might want to consider using `lmer` in the `lme4` package or the `MCMCglmm` package depending on what kind of factor `y` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Akaike’s Information Criterion ($AIC$) for model selection where:
$$
AIC = -2ln(L)-2k
$$
Though a better alternative is often $AIC_c$, which is the second-order Akaike’s Information Criterion ($AIC_c$).  $AIC_c$ is corrected for small sample size with an addtion bias-correction term because $AIC$ can perform poorly when the ratio of sample size to the number parameters in the model is small (Burnham and Anderson 2002).
$$
AIC_c = -2ln(L)-2k+\frac{2k(k+1)}{(n-k-1)}
$$
In fact, I would always use $AIC_c$ since the bias-correction term goes to zero as sample size increases.  However, there are some types of models where it is difficult to determine sample size (i.e., hierarchical models of abundance [see links to these model types here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33686/books-about-model-selection-in-ecology/33691#33691)).

$AIC$ or $AIC_c$ can be recaled to $\mathsf{\Delta}_i=AIC_i-minAIC$ where the best model will have $\mathsf{\Delta}_i=0$.  Further, these values can be used to estimate relative strength of evidence ($w_i$) for the alternative models where:
$$
w_i = \frac{e^{(-0.5\mathsf{\Delta}_i)}}{\sum_{r=1}^Re^{(-0.5\mathsf{\Delta}_i)}}
$$
This is often refered to as the "weight of evidence" for model $i$ from the model set.  As $\mathsf{\Delta}_i$ increases, $w_i$ decreases suggesting model $i$ is less plausible.  Also, the weights of evidence for the models in a model set can be use in model averaging and multi-model inference.

Comment: Also, I have posted a few good papers and books that discuss the use of AIC [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18746/can-the-aicc-corrected-akaike-information-criterion-measure-be-used-for-post-h/33429#33429).